# Google Analytics Dynamic event value. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, dom-events, code-analysis

Any suggestions as to why this dynamic value will not report report in GA?

To start:

I have created a way to split the URL parameters up so that I can insert the value from the URL that I want into the Google Analytics event onclick tracking.

This is an example of my URL:

```
<http://www.example.org/sweden/se/stod-oss/gava/info/?view=DDM&price=118>
```

The *price* in the url is a dynamic amount.

This is how I successfully split the url up in the  :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var params = {};

            if (location.search) {
                var parts = location.search.substring(1).split('&');

                for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    var nv = parts[i].split('=');
                    if (!nv[0]) continue;
                    params[nv[0]] = nv[1] || true;
                }
            }

        </script>
```

So that works correctly and when I insert params.price into the button submit it works fine wen placed in the category section, like so:

```
<button type="submit" onClick="_gaq.push(['SE._trackEvent', 'se_donationpages', 'submitinfo', params.price,, false])" class="btn btn-gp btn-gp-special">Next<i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i></button>
```

Google Analytics registers this fine in the reports.

But, this is not where I want this. I would like the price value to be inserted in the value section, like so:

```
<button type="submit" onClick="_gaq.push(['SE._trackEvent', 'se_donationpages', 'submitinfo', 'payment',params.price, false])" class="btn btn-gp btn-gp-special">Nästa  <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i></button>
```

So, when I do this one above, Google Analytics does not register the event at all.

I thought there might be a problem with the value being a string, so I converted the price parameter to a integer like so in the head:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var params = {};

            if (location.search) {
                var parts = location.search.substring(1).split('&');

                for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    var nv = parts[i].split('=');
                    if (!nv[0]) continue;
                    params[nv[0]] = nv[1] || true;
                }
            }

            var price_param = params.price;
            var view_param = params.view;

            var price_param_int = parseInt(price_param)

        </script>
```

and inserted the variable into the button code like so:

```
<button type="submit" onClick="_gaq.push(['SE._trackEvent', 'se_donationpages', 'submitinfo', 'payment',price_param_int, false])" class="btn btn-gp btn-gp-special">Next<i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i></button>
```

...but, this doesnt report in GA :(

Any suggestions as to why this dynamic value will not report report in GA?

It's boggling my mind!

Answer (score 1):

You are right that it must be an integer variable type.  I don't know why GA doesn't just convert it automatically..

perhaps you simply typoed while posting, but in your code, you assign the integer-converted value to `price_param_int` (notice the lack of "s" on "param") but in your GA code you reference `price_params_int`

**edit**

Okay you mentioned in comment that it was just a typo when posting.. well I tested your code and it works fine.  So here's another dumb question: are you sure you are going to your page with the `price` parameter actually in the URL? e.g.

`http://www.yoursite.com/page.html?price=123`

If you are and it's still not working then.. you must have something else going on that's affecting your code, because when I just have on a test page GA code and that button and the query param grabbing code you posted, it works fine.

Comment: @NicholasKnight sweet! if the question is solved then can you click the checkbox next to the answer? :D

Comment: Crayon, no sorry I meant the typo was just a typo in this particular post but the problem still remains as is.

Comment: @NicholasKnight Aaah okay.. well see my edited post.